# Different types of validations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a User model

is there a difference between

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def validate
    errors.add_to_base "name should not be nil" if name.nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validates` macro is more flexible, as it also allows you to do things like:

```
validates :name, :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/,
:message => "Only letters allowed" }, :length => { :in => 6..20 }
```

The `validate` method is really a quick and easy way to do custom validations when existing ones do not exist. (When custom validations get too complex, then you should usually move them into custom validators and use the `validates` macro).

See more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- the first will fail to save an empty string, whereas the second will allow it.

Comment: sure but assuming that both check for nil?, everything else is same ?

Comment: i mean do we need to explicitly call user.valid? in the second case ?  or they will be validated as usual ?

Comment: `valid?` calls `validate` along with the validation methods. (IIRC, the `validates` macros all chain validations into the `validate` method`

Comment: so i need to call user.vallid? explicitly before saving in both the cases ? wont they automatically apply ?

Comment: no, you don't need to call user.valid? -- in both cases, sending `save` to an invalid User will return false and not do anything